# What simple method will measure decoupling betwen two antennas?

Tags: antenna

I have 2 antennas which are quite close to each other. I would like to have at least a rough idea of the decoupling between those 2 antennas. I do not own a network analyzer.

I was thinking of using a transmitter set to a known power on the first antenna and a wattmeter terminated with a dummy load on the other antenna. Might this work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. But, how much decoupling do you need? In other words it all depends on how you're using the two antennas. If one is for your transmitter and the other for a receiver then you definitely do not want the receiver and transmitter on the same frequency when you transmit until you know if it is safe. Most receivers have limits as to signal levels that can be tolerated. You have to find that information and then a way to measure the signal level generated at the input to the receiver when your transmitter is transmitting and the power level you intend to use. Receiver signal levels are usually measured in microvolts, uV. Some maximum level is usually given, exceed it at the risk of destroying the receiver.

Answer (score 2):

That will give you a rough idea of the coupling, but note that the dummy load would have an SWR of 1:1, while the antenna to the radio might not.  Your coupling will depend on the impedance matching between the radio as well as the antenna, so you can only get so far with an SWR meter and a dummy load.